# E RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set. - Pytest

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

Im trying to run Pytest with Flask and I get the following error:

My Error is:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\graha\Documents\GitHub\tagr-api-py> pytest tests/test_config.py
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\Users\graha\Documents\GitHub\tagr-api-py\tests\conftest.py'.
tests\__init__.py:3: in <module>
    app = init_app()
application\__init__.py:27: in init_app
    db.init_app(app)
venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py:355: in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
E   RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
```

So my test_config.py is:

```py
"""Tests the flask app configuration app.config.py"""
import os
from config import Config, TestingConfig


def test_config(test_app):
    test_app.config.from_object(Config)
    assert test_app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] == os.getenv("JWT_SECRET_KEY")
    assert not test_app.config["TESTING"]
    assert test_app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] == os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")


def test_testing_config(test_app):
    test_app.config.from_object(TestingConfig)
    assert test_app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] == os.getenv("DATABASE_TESTING_URL")
    assert test_app.config["TESTING"]
```

and my conftest.py:

```py
from application import db
import pytest

from mock import patch
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from config import TestingConfig
from . import app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app():
    """fixture for testing the application"""
    application = app
    application.config.from_object(TestingConfig)
    with application.app_context():
        yield application


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_db():
    """fixture for cleaning and initializing the database"""
    db.create_all()
    yield db
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
```

and the error refers to my init_app which is also as so:

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_cors import CORS

# Global accessible libraries
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
JWTManager = JWTManager()
migration = Migrate()
mail = Mail()
cors = CORS()


def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Setup plugins
    db.init_app(app)
```

Please take note that when i run just the flask app everything runs absolutely perfect and all endpoints are good, its just when i run pytests